# External stylesheet referencing anomoly

Tags: html, css

So I'm kind of a programming noob, but I thought I had CSS referencing down...apparently not.  I've referenced stylesheets, I've done it externally, internally, you know, the works.  For some reason, however, when I went back to tweak an older app I had worked on that had the CSS initially included within the HTML and moved the CSS out, then referenced it, the CSS oddly stopped working altogether.  I've got the directory set up as follows:

```
App name (folder)
   static (folder)
      main.css
   templates (folder)
      template_referencing_css.html
   main.py
   app.yaml
```

So here are the various references I've tried with main.css being inside the static folder:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" />
```

Here is what I tried when I moved main.css to templates folder with the template referencing it:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

The css file is just a longer version of things like:

```
body    {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    width: 850px;
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
    color: #008B8B;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Tried a full URL? Is "App name" actually *in* the URL?

Comment: you put it in the <head> part of the HTML i suppose ?

Comment: This is a web app? Can you browse to the CSS file when your app is running?

Comment: Did you put the code in the HEAD of your html? / is there a live version to look at

Comment: Wes, I hadn't tried the full URL.  You mean start the CSS reference with  "/App name/static...."?

Comment: I can't browse to the main.css, no.  I just tried.

Answer (score 0):

remove the leading slash -

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css" />
```

Comment: oh i misread your post... sorry about that. you should be able to use the ../ syntax to hit it. Nothing is happening?

Comment: absolutely nothing.  It's weird too because I have literally the EXACT CSS in the main.css file as I did in-line.  I've referenced every app I've done this way and never had an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In general this isn't necessarily a good idea, but try to use the full absolute path (like "C:/Whatever/another_dir/main.css").  At least this will tell you if the problem is finding the css file or not.